# How to know if php is running single instance?

Tags: php, download, server

I want to analyze the time at which new articles are posted on a website. For this, I wish to run php script to download homepage every hour for at least 1 month, how do I make sure that the script is running and has a single instance only?

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 720; $x++) {
    file_put_contents( $x . ".html", file_get_contents("http://example.com"));
    sleep ( 3600 );
}
```

Comment: Considered using CRON to run it every hour?  I'd trust that more than a script left running for a month.  As for single instance Google `mutex` or `semaphore` - probably overkill for your needs but still good to know.

Comment: You're not going to go and do something insane like run it through the web server, are you?

Comment: Not that having one PHP script run continuously for a month is a good idea, but why do you expect it might have more than a single instance running at the same time?

Comment: Hi, thanks everyone for the response, I found CRON to be most suitable :) ficuscr thanks, Ignacio yup! Juhana in case I refreshed the page!

Comment: Sidenote: You forgot a `$`for `x`  => `file_put_contents( $x` - Plus, use a dot to concatenate, not a `+` - `file_put_contents( $x . ".html"` - Right now, `x` is considered a constant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CRON to run PHP script every hour. To be sure it's single instance you could additionally create temp file before downloading and deleting after download. Script should check if temp file exists and exit php script if so.